# How can I use XPath to find the minimum value of an attribute in a set of elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

If I have XML like:

```
<foo>
  <bar id="1" score="192" />
  <bar id="2" score="227" />
  <bar id="3" score="105" />
  ...
</foo>
```

Can I use XPath to find the minimum and maximum values of `score`?

**Edit**: The tool i'm using ([Andariel](http://andariel.uworks.net/) ant tasks) doesn't support the XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out the tool does not support XPath 2.0.

XPath 1.0 doesn't have the fancy `min()` and `max()` functions, so to find these values we need to be a little tricky with the XPath logic, and compare the values on the siblings of the node:

Maximum:

```
/foo/bar[not(preceding-sibling::bar/@score >= @score) 
    and not(following-sibling::bar/@score > @score)]/@score
```

Minimum:

```
/foo/bar[not(preceding-sibling::bar/@score <= @score) 
    and not(following-sibling::bar/@score < @score)]/@score
```

*If embedding these queries in XML files like XSLT or ant scripts, remember to encode `<` and `>` as `&lt;` respecting `&gt;`.*

Comment: nice job! I tried the top ranked solution first but that one does not exclude duplicate maxima/minima.

Answer (score 44):

Here's a slightly shorter solution.

Maximum:

```
/foo/bar/@score[not(. < ../../bar/@score)][1]
```

Minimum:

```
/foo/bar/@score[not(. > ../../bar/@score)][1]
```

I've edited the predicate so that it's applicable to any sequence of `bar`, even if you decide to change the path. Note that parent of attribute is the element to which it belongs.

*If embedding these queries in XML files like XSLT or ant scripts, remember to encode `<` and `>` as `&lt;` respecting `&gt;`.*

Comment: Cool...but I can't guarantee that the there won't be (for example) multiple maximum values of `score`. This would list a value for each element that contained the maximum..

Comment: Probably you want to use `number(.)` because otherwise it compares string values of attributes. Am I right?

Comment: You shouldn't need that, since relative comparison operators will automatically apply it to both sides as needed. It's only `==` and `!=` which will default to string comparisons unless one operand is a number.

Comment: nice XPath 1.0 solution! I run it with the example in the question, appending the element with score 227 at the end and it gave me a duplicate result for the maximum ->   /foo/bar/@score[not(. < ../../bar/@score)][1] -> would it be possible that you take another look?

Answer (score 6):

This should work ...

```
max(foo/bar/@score)
```

... and ...

```
min(foo/bar/@score)
```

... check out this [function reference](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

Comment: Ok. This is XPath 2.0, I will check it out.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon the thread and didn't find an answer that worked for me, so where is what I eventually ended up using...

Outputs the lowest value, of course you could choose to output the @id from the node with the lowest value instead of you choose.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/foo">
  <xsl:sort select="@score"/>
  <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:value-of select="@score"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The same for the maximum value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/foo">
  <xsl:sort select="@score" order="descending"/>
  <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:value-of select="@score"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is five years old. Just adding some more options for whoever may search and come across this.

Something similar to this worked for me in XSLT 2.0.

```
min(//bar[@score !='']/@score)
```

The `!=''` was to avoid a nulls which brought up NaN values (there's probably a better way to do that)

Here is a working xpath/xquery:

```
//bar/@score[@score=min(//*[@score !='']/number(@score))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//foo/bar[not(preceding-sibling::bar/@score <= @score) and not(following-sibling::bar/@score <= @score)]
```

Maybe this will work on XPath 1.0.