# Using XPATH to compute the minimum attribute element and add it to another attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, minimum

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128745/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-find-the-minimum-value-of-an-attribute-in-a-set-of-elemen), in which the author asks how to find the minimum attribute of an set of elements.  I'm a beginner at xpath and I'm having trouble taking that answer and adding it to my XSLT.  I need to find the minimum price of a Plan (see below) and add an attribute to the Subdivision containing that minimum.

I have the following XML snippet:

```
<Subdivision Status="Active">
  <SubdivisionName>Chesla</SubdivisionName>
  <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
    <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
    <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
    <BasePrice>200500.0000</BasePrice>
  </Plan>
  <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
    <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
    <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
    <BasePrice>270000.0000</BasePrice>
  </Plan>
```

*Note: There can be multiple Subdivisions in my XML document.  I'm just showing one in my example for the sake of brevity.*

My final output is the same as the input except that a PriceLow attribute has been added to the Subdivision element containing the minimum BasePrice of all Plans who are siblings of the Subdivision:

```
<Subdivision Status="Active" PriceLow="200500.00"> <==== ADDED!!!
  <SubdivisionName>Chesla</SubdivisionName>
  <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
    <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
    <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
    <BasePrice>200500.00</BasePrice>
  </Plan>
  <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
    <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
    <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
    <BasePrice>270000.00</BasePrice>
  </Plan>
```

My incomplete xsl file looks like this:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Subdivision">
   ... something goes here ...
</xsl:template>
```

Could someone help me complete this XSLT file?  I'm reading a few books on XSLT, but in the meantime I need to complete this project soon.

Cheers,
Bret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Subdivision">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:attribute name="PriceLow">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Plan/BasePrice" mode="min">
          <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" data-type="number" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="min">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or a more succinct, but possibly less efficient approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Subdivision">
    <Subdivision PriceLow="{Plan/BasePrice[not(. > current()/Plan/BasePrice)]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'PriceLow'] | node()" />
    </Subdivision>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When either of these is run on this sample data:

```
<root>
  <Subdivision Status="Active">
    <SubdivisionName>Chesla</SubdivisionName>
    <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200500.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
      <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>270000.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
  </Subdivision>

  <Subdivision Status="Active">
    <SubdivisionName>Newhaven</SubdivisionName>
    <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200900.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
      <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200100.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="QuadrupleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>111</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200050.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="QuintupleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>222</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200300.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
  </Subdivision>
</root>
```

The result is:

```
<root>
  <Subdivision Status="Active" PriceLow="200500.0000">
    <SubdivisionName>Chesla</SubdivisionName>
    <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200500.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
      <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>270000.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
  </Subdivision>

  <Subdivision Status="Active" PriceLow="200050.0000">
    <SubdivisionName>Newhaven</SubdivisionName>
    <Plan Type="SingleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>555</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200900.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="MultiFamily">
      <PlanNumber>444</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Westfield</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200100.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="QuadrupleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>111</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200050.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
    <Plan Type="QuintupleFamily">
      <PlanNumber>222</PlanNumber>
      <PlanName>Pinewood</PlanName>
      <BasePrice>200300.0000</BasePrice>
    </Plan>
  </Subdivision>
</root>
```