# Finding minimum value using XPath 1.0 does not work

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to find the minimum value in a certain element from an XML document (it's actually a HTML table that is translated to XML). However, this does not work as intended.

The query is similar to the one used in [How can I use XPath to find the minimum value of an attribute in a set of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128745/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-find-the-minimum-value-of-an-attribute-in-a-set-of-elemen). It looks like this:

```
/table[@id="search-result-0"]/tbody/tr[
    not(substring-before(td[1], " ") > substring-before(../tr/td[1], " "))
]
```

Executed on the example XML

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="search-result-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header headerSortDown">Preis</th>
            <th class="header headerSortDown">Zustand</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">20 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">25 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">35 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">14 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
            <td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the query returns the following result:

```
<tr>
<td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
<td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
</tr>
-----------------------
<tr>
<td width="45px">14 CHF</td>
<td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
</tr>
-----------------------
<tr>
<td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
<td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
</tr>
-----------------------
<tr>
<td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
<td width="175px">Gebraucht, aber noch in Ordnung</td>
</tr>
```

Why are there more nodes returned than one? There should only be exactly one node returned as there is only a single minimum. Does anybody see what's wrong with the query? It should only return the node containing the `14 CHF`.

Results obtained using http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I decided to use XSLT instead. This is the style sheet that I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

    <xsl:template match="//table[@id=\'search-result-0\']/tbody">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="tr/td[@width=\'45px\']">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., \' \')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>

                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., \' \')"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/> <!-- ignore the plain text -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

TML has already pointed out why your current path expression does not work, but has not suggested a working alternative.

The reason is simple, as @Tomalak has said:

> I agree with Mathias. This actually is impossible in XPath 1.0 without changing the input XML.

I add this answer to elaborate on the way you'd have to preprocess your XML *before* searching for the minimum amount of CHF. And remember: This is so complicated because you asked for a solution in XPath 1.0. With XPath 2.0, your problem could be solved with a single path expression.

---

**XML Design**

I think that your question illustrates why XML design is actually essential when working with XML.
Why? Because your problem boils down to the following: Your XML is designed in a way that makes it difficult to manipulate the content. More precisely, in a `td` element like this:

```
<td width="45px">15 CHF</td>
```

There is an amount (as a number) and a currency, both in the text node of the `td` element. If your XML input was designed in a more clever or canonical way, it would look like:

```
<td width="45px" currency="CHF">15</td>
```

See the difference? Now, different kinds of content are clearly separated from each other.

---

**XPath Revised**

Assuming that in the newly designed XML, the only content of a `tr/td[1]` element is the number, the XPath expression by Pavel Minaev that you used can be made to work:

```
/table[@id="search-result-0"]/tbody/tr[not(td[1] > ../tr/td[1])][1]
```

**XML Result** (tested with [the tool you use](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php))

```
<tr>
<td width="45px">14</td>
<td width="175px">Ausgepack und doch nie gebraucht</td>
</tr>
```

---

**Why does [Pavel's expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129929/1987598) not work, simply because I add `substring-before`?**

You found part of the answer yourself already. It has to do with how sequences of items are handled in XPath 1.0 functions.

`substring-before()` is an XPath 1.0 function that expects two arguments, both of them strings. And, most importantly, if you define a *sequence of strings* as the first argument of `substring-before()`, only the **first string** will be processed, the others will be ignored.

Pavel's answer, adapted to this question:

```
tr[not(td[1] > ../tr/td[1])][1]
```

Relies on the fact that the second part of the expression, `../tr/td[1]`, finds *all* first `td` child elements of all `tr` elements of `tbody`. There is no function involved, and there is nothing wrong with a sequence as the operand of `>`.

If we need `substring-before()` because the text content is actually both a number (that we want) and a currency (that we'd like to ignore), we have to wrap it around both parts of the expression:

```
tr[not(substring-before(td[1],' ') > substring-before(../tr/td[1],' '))][1]
```

No problem on the left side of `>`, because there is only one `td[1]` for the current `tr`. But on the right, there is a *sequence* of nodes, namely `../tr/td[1]`. Sadly, `substring-before()` is only capable of processing the *first* of them.

See the answer by @TML for the consequences of that.

Comment: Great expansion and detail, Mathias.

Comment: I see. As I cannot change the source document, I came up with an XSLT solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The XPath query you're using here would only find the "minimum" in cases where there are no duplicate values, and the values are sorted prior to being written into nodes; this is because it's only comparing the current value `substring-before(td[1], " ")` to the first value found `substring-before(../tr/td[1], " ")`. To break down the comparisons:

```
[1] not(15 > 15)
[2] not(20 > 15)
[3] not(25 > 15)
[4] not(35 > 15)
[5] not(14 > 15)
[6] not(15 > 15)
[7] not(15 > 15)
```

Comparisons 1, 5, 6, and 7 evaluate to true (the left-hand side is NOT greater than the right-hand side).

Comment: You are right. Calling a function on a node set only returns the result of the first node instead of a set again. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: @str I am tempted to say that this is not possible in XPath 1.0. Can you manipulate the elements beforehand? If `substring-before` can be a separate step that is performed before you apply the XPath expression (so that `<td width="45px">15</td>` is left) - then I have a solution for you.

Comment: I agree with Mathias. This *actually is* impossible in XPath 1.0 without changing the input XML.