# Xpath - how control every element value with others?

Tags: xml, loops, xpath, xsd, schematron

EXAMPLE:
My **XML**:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
    </a>
</root>
```

- ***A now, how to control that every "b" element has got only the same one value(not only "1")?***
- Is it possible? I found only, but it doesnt work: `//a/b != ./b`
- I have no idea except some loop or count by value in element ... but it cant in xpath, or not?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Given this sample XML, what do you want the XPath to return?

Comment: @har07 - probably true/false ... every b is the same or not. I know, it doesnt make a lot of sence here, in practice i need it for atribute.

Comment: Only stating *"but it doesnt work"* without telling exactly why it does not work and not providing a code example is not good style to ask. Especially if you feel unsure with the correct technical wording, showing your code example can help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of different values for all `/*/a/b` element nodes, you can count the distinct values of those elements:

```
count(/*/a/b[not(. = preceding::b)])
```

This expression will return 1 if there is one distinct value, 2 if two (as in your case) or 0 if there are no `/*/a/b` elements in the document.

PHP Example:

```
<?php

$buffer = <<<XML
<root>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
    </a>
</root>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo $xpath->evaluate('count(/*/a/b[not(. = preceding::b)])');  # echoes 2
```

Comment: Very pretty, it should be faster i guess ... also very thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "control" that you actually want to have a Boolean return value telling you if all `<b>` elements have the same value you could use this expression:

```
count(/root/a/b[. != ../b]) = 0
```

It determines the `<b>`'s whose value is not like the values of other `<b>`'s. If the count is greater than 1 there is mismatch in at least one b so that the expression will be `false`. If the result set is empty the count will be 0 and the expression will be `true`.

This answer was inspired by [How can I use XPath to find the minimum value of an attribute in a set of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128745).