# XPath To Find Maximum Value In A Formula

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find the maximum of different values, some that are mathematical equations.

Below is my XML:

```
<History AccountBalance="100" 
         AccountLimit="500" 
         AccountBalanceAvailable="400" 
         ValueX="50" 
         ValueY="75"/>
```

I want to find the Max of:

```
Max((AccountBalance + ValueX + ValueY), (AccountBalanceAvailable - ValueY))
```

I'm new to XPath and can't find examples of something like this.

Don't even know where to start. In this example

This would evaluate to `Max(225 or 325) = 325`

I don't know how to do that in XPATH.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128745/how-can-i-use-xpath-to-find-the-minimum-value-of-an-attribute-in-a-set-of-elemen

Is a scripting language solution any use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 2.0,

```
max((@AccountBalance + @ValueX + @Value, @AccountBalanceAvailable - @ValueY))
```

Note the double parens, because `max()` doesn't take two arguments, it takes a single argument which is a sequence of numbers.

In XPath 1.0 it's much trickier because there is no max function and no conditional expression. Depending on what host language you are using, I think I would return both values to the calling application and have the calling application compare them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-max) function from Xpath 2.0.