# Obtaining min/max values of an element with xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an xml sheet like:

```
<f:device-list>
    <f:device name="Voltage Converter" quantity="2" serial_number="20011">
        <f:weight units="pounds">3.00</f:weight>
    </f:device>
    <f:device name="24-port switch" quantity="2" serial_number="24PORTSW-004">
        <f:weight units="pounds">3.34</f:weight>
    </f:device>
</f:device-list>
```

I am obtaining the weight of the devices using simplexml and xpath like so:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//f:weight[@units="pounds"]') as $weightLB) {
        echo $weightLB;
        echo "</br>";
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can obtain the min and max values of the weight element. I have looked at many solutions regarding xpath but most cover attribute values and are not applicable to a sheet formatted like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `max($weightLB)` and `min($weightLB)`?

Comment: It is a simple xml object and throws the error "When only one parameter is given, it must be an array"

Comment: If you want a pure XPath version - have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129929/1213708.  For this case Max - `//f:weight[@units="pounds"][. > //f:weight[@units="pounds"]]`

Comment: @NigelRen that answer has some problems. Check my solution below https://stackoverflow.com/a/57981655/11102282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map all the values to an array then use `max` and `min` functions:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <device-list>
    <device name="Voltage Converter" quantity="2" serial_number="20011">
        <weight units="pounds">3.00</weight>
    </device>
    <device name="24-port switch" quantity="2" serial_number="24PORTSW-004">
        <weight units="pounds">3.34</weight>
    </device>
</device-list>
XML;

$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$weights = array_map(function($elem) {
    return $elem->__toString();
}, $simpleXml->xpath('//weight[@units="pounds"]'));

echo "Min: " .min($weights) . "<br/>";
echo "Max: " .max($weights);
```

Output:

> Min: 3.00
>
> Max: 3.34

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: You could case `$elem` to a float instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this pure XPath 1.0 answer because the linked one in comments is wrong for this case. The general idiom for maximum:

```
($node-set[not(. < $node-set)])[1]
```

Meanning:

> Select the first (in document order) from the node set with number
>   value not less than any other in the node set.

For your input (**now wellformed**):

```
<f:device-list xmlns:f="dummy">  
  <f:device name="Voltage Converter" quantity="2" serial_number="20011"> 
    <f:weight units="pounds">3.00</f:weight> 
  </f:device>  
  <f:device name="24-port switch" quantity="2" serial_number="24PORTSW-004"> 
    <f:weight units="pounds">3.34</f:weight> 
  </f:device> 
</f:device-list>
```

This XPath 1.0 expression (with `f` prefix bound to `dummy` namespace URI):

```
(//f:weight[@units='pounds'][not(. < //f:weight[@units='pounds'])])[1]
```

It selects:

```
<f:weight xmlns:f="dummy" units="pounds">3.34</f:weight>
```

Check in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1969ef047d90f2efbb0dcc1d1e131428

**Do note**: positional predicates (like `[1]` abbreviated form) work against location step axis, meaning that if all the nodes in the set are first child then you would need parentheses to get the first in document order.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure where you are saying how the linked answer didn't work for this case.  You seems to swaped < for not >.

Comment: @NigelRen There is also a proper explanation of positional predicates. Check the linked answer against OP input sample with duplicated maximum [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/2c6ca13a1cd0c6659350c577ad0b3c5a)